NamedPipeClientStream cannot connect without UAC
I'm writing an executable to send data to an open process (a Unity game) through a NamedPipe as to "simulate" deeplinks coming from a browser using a custom URI Scheme. This means both the pipe Client and the pipe Server will only ever run on the local user for IPC.
The game starts a NamedPipeServerStream and awaits until a Client connects and sends data:
var pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(everyone, PipeAccessRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow));
                
pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(PIPE_NAME, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, 
            PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 
            8192, 8192, pipeSecurity);

try
{
    await pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}

My Deeplink.exe (a WinExe built with Rider) creates a NamedPipeClientStream when opened and tries to connect:
using NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new(".", PIPE_NAME, 
            PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
try
{
    pipeClient.Connect(PIPE_TIMEOUT);
}

This works correctly only when Deeplink.exe is Ran as Admin.
If not, pipeClient.Connect throws an UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
I can't have my app requesting UAC every time a deeplink is used! From the public mono repo, this seems to match the UnauthorizedAccess_IODenied_NoPathName string, but I have checked and the PIPE_NAMEs are the correct.
At first I thought this was due to Deeplink.exe being placed under the C:/Program Files folder, next to where the Unity program is, but no, the issue persists even when trying to run it from the desktop. I have tried to use PipeAccessRights.FullAccess instead, but no luck there either.
Seeing as the UAC is the only difference between it working and not, I have to assume the problem is permission-related (tho I was expecting WorldSid to allow anyone and anything to access the pipe).
Is there something I overlooked? Is there really no way to connect to a pipe without admin permissions?

Update
For a bit of context, the game executable is first ran from a Game Launcher program (that I have also developed in Unity) that simply calls:
Process process = new();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "/path/to/game.exe";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

process.Start();

I have found that:

Opening Game.exe directly and then running Deeplink.exe works as expected.
Opening Launcher.exe, which then starts the Game.exe process, and then running Deeplink.exe does not work. UAC should not be necessary at any step in the process.

Sill dumbfounded about this. I started assuming my NamedPipeClientStream was at fault, but maybe starting Game.exe with these particular StartInfo properties is what's preventing the NamedPipeServerStream from being created correctly?

Update 2
The mystery thickens: I tried starting game.exe with UseShellExecute = false, and now the pipes communicate correctly... but only sometimes! It seems to work about 75% of the time. I truly have no idea what's sporadically denying my Client pipe access, the Server one always starts according to my logs.

" Is there really no way to connect to a pipe without admin permissions?" - yes, there is a way, when pipes are used strictly for IPC. Using server and client constructor with just pipe name will guarantee this. I am not sure which setting exactly (security? transmittion mode?) causes UAC to popup up though.

@Sinatr just to clarify: I'm not seeing an unexpected UAC popup. What I'm saying is
I'm forced to right-click > Run as Admin for the intended behavior to work.

The exact content of PIPE_NAME may be important.  Are you using ProtectedPrefix\Administrators (or any other protected prefix)?  Are you using a local or global name?

It may also be worth testing whether your Launcher.exe has permission to create a pipe where DeepLink.exe can find it.  If not, that is likely being inherited by Game.exe in a way that has nothing to do with your StartInfo configuration.

Furthermore, I'm assuming that your game EXE is running as admin because this is a very common (and lamentable) practice.  But this information should be added to the question.

@BenVoigt PIPE_NAME doesn't contain protected words or special chars. I debated sharing it as it contained the name of the company I work for. You can assume it's "pipeName". As for admin privileges, the game does not need them. The only instance in which any one of my applications needs UAC is when the Launcher is installing files for the first time and writing Registry Keys for the URI Scheme.

The mystery thickens: I tried starting game.exe with UseShellExecute = false, and now the pipes communicate correctly... but only sometimes! I really can't tell what I am doing differently each time, at least it's working about 75% of the time.

Use a tool like sysinternals PipeList or Process Explorer to look at the pipe, see if you find any differences between how it appears between working and failing cases.  https://www.aloneguid.uk/posts/2022/09/list-named-pipes-windows/ shows basic usage of those tools.

I took a look at the pipe with different methods as @BenVoigt suggested, but they all consistently gave me different results (sometimes PipeList would list my pipe, but Process Explorer would not, and vice versa). Whether they get listed correctly or not doesn't seem to be correlated with the Client being able to connect or not.

Answering my own question as I think I have found why this was happening and how to fix it.
It would seem the issue was that, if my Launcher was opened with elevated privileges, then any process ran by it would also inherit them. This meant that my NamedPipeServerStream would sometimes be running with elevated permissions, but my NamedPipeClientStream would always run without them. Regardless of the access rules I set during their creation, my pipe Client would always refuse to connect to it.
Since I didn't need the game.exe to have elevated access, I looked into how to un-elevate a sub-process started by an elevated one, and ended up passing through explorer.exe as suggested in this blog post.
// If the Launcher has UAC, use the explorer to launch the game
if (FileUtility.HasElevatedPermissions())
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new()
    {
        FileName = "explorer.exe",
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Arguments = $"\"{exePath}\""
    };
    Process.Start(processInfo);
}
// If the Launcher doesn't have UAC, open the game normally
else
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new()
    {
        FileName = exePath,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "open"
    };
    Process.Start(processInfo);
}

This seems to do the trick, game.exe always opens without privileges and the deeplinker.exe pipe can communicate without issue.
Thanks to both @Sinatr and @BenVoigt for their suggestions.

If anyone's interested in HasElevatedPermissions(), I try to create a directory under C:/Program Files and return whether I succeed or not.
public static bool HasElevatedPermissions(string _path = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_path))
        _path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
        
    float random = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    var path = @$"{_path}\temp{random}"; // Random to prevent user interference
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    Directory.Delete(path);
    return true;
}

Not the best approach I admit, but I couldn't find anything that could easily work from a Unity program.
